# placing viewpager with sliding tabs inside fragments as a nested format

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**What i am trying to do:**

1. I am using a drawer where i have 10 fragments
2. Inside one of the fragment i am trying to add view pager with
   sliding tabs(that has view pager indicator as per jake wharton)

---

**What is happening:**

1. When i tried to do this i get [error as described here in one of my
   other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27742128/1083093)
2. I am not able to bring the architecture described in the figure
   below

---

**Question::**

1. Is placing view pager with sliding tabs not possible inside
   fragments ?
2. If so are there any samples online ? (Jake wharton sample is done
   with placing widgets in activity not fragments)
3. If any other way is available are there any open source library for
   this

---

***Note:*** i am aware nested way is not advised, but i need to get this architecture

---

**Architecture i am trying to get it:**

[image: fig]

Comment: Have you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

At first, you can try this sample from Google https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html. It also contains the SlidingTabLayout class, try it, if you use something different.

This project is similar to your (has the same layout) except navigation drawer.

So, let's do the following things:

your main layout may look like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/drawer_back"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/drawer_back"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For fragment with sliding tabs use the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

    <yourpackage.slidinglayout.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

After that you should create a Fragments for your ViewPager and etc. but I think, you've already done it.

Fragment with sliding tabs and ViewPager - it's up to you.

On drawer item with sliding tabs clicked, simple use the FragmentTransaction:

```
mCurrentFragment = new SlidingTabsFragment();
mTransaction.replace(R.id.content_fragment, mCurrentFragment);
mTransaction.commit();
```